# Sequential batch processing vs parallel batch processing?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

In deep learning based model training, in general batch of inputs are passed. For example for training a deep learning model with [512] dimensional input feature vector, say for batch size= 4, we mainly pass [4,512] dimenional input. I am curious what are the logical significance of passing the same input after flattening the input across the batch and channel dimenions [2048]. Logically the locality structure will be destroyed but will it significanlty speed up my implementation? And can it affect the performance?

Answer (score 2):

In supervised learning, you would usually be working with data points (*e.g.* a feature vector or a multi-dimensional input such as an image) paired with some kind of ground-truth (a label for classifications tasks, or another multi-dimensional object altogether). Feeding to your model a flattened tensor containing multiple data points would not make sense in terms of supervision. Assuming you do an inference this way, what would be the supervision signal at the output level of your model? Would you combine the labels as well? All of this seem to depend heavily on the use case: is there some kind of temporal coherence between the elements of the batch?

Performance-wise, this has no implications whatsoever. Tensors are already *'flattened'* by design since their memory is laid out in contiguous memory buffers. The idea of multi-dimensionality is an abstraction layer provided by those libraries (namely NumPy's arrays and Torch's tensors) to allow for easier and more flexible control over data.